# Parsing U+00BE (¾) to number in python

Tags: python, string, unicode, data-conversion

I have a string which represents a ingredient with an amount, unit, description and so on.

`¾ cup fresh pineapple, cut in small chunks or canned pineapple tidbits, drained`

I'd like to parse this string into an object which holds all the different characteristics of this ingredient.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to convert the number (¾) from the Unicode representation to a normal number.

How can I parse this sentence to get something like 3/4 or 0.75 back as result?

Comment: why not just check `if line[i] == '¾'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.numeric(u'¾')
```

will give you 0.75 (or without u if Python 3+)